# How to login to Twitter using htmlunit in Java?

Tags: java, exception, twitter, authentication

I am trying to login to Twitter using Java's htmlunit packages. But I get the error: 
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.twitter.com/");
    HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(1);
    form.reset();
    HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("session[password]");

    username.setText("xxxxxxx");

    HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("session[password]");

    password.setText("xxxxxxx");

    HtmlInput button = form.getInputByValue("Log in");
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    HtmlPage p = button.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line in your code causes the problem

```
HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("session[password]");
```

It should be

```
HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("session[username_or_email]");
```